# Issue with Android In App Purchase skuDetailsList null

Tags: android, android-studio, in-app-purchase

I have the following code which gets executed when I press the Purchase button in the view.

```
private void initiatePurchase() {

    // Purchase Item
    skuList.add(PRODUCT_ID); // <-- Product added to Play Console and Active

    SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();

    params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(INAPP);

    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {

            if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {


                Log.e(TAG, "*** skuDetailsList: " + skuDetailsList); // <-- Returns null!?


                if (skuDetailsList != null && skuDetailsList.size() > 0) {

                    BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSkuDetails(skuDetailsList.get(0)).build();

                    billingClient.launchBillingFlow(CreatePoolDetailsActivity.this, flowParams);

                } else {

                    // This keeps getting executed - Purchase Item not Found!?
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Purchase Item not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Error " + billingResult.getDebugMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        }

    });

}
```

The issue is that the `skuDetailsList` is always Null (size == 0) and the error message `Purchase Item not Found` is thrown as a result; which I do not understand why, since my In App Purchases are setup correctly and active in the developer console?!

Does anyone know why that is and how I can resolve?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code, you have to initialize the billing client.

```
 private lateinit var billingClient: BillingClient
private val skuList = listOf("product_1", "product_2", "product_3", "product_4")

private fun setupBillingClient() {
    billingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(BaseActivity.mContext!!)
        .enablePendingPurchases()
        .setListener(this)
        .build()
    billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
        override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
            if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
                loadAllSKUs()

            }
        }

        override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
            // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
            // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
            Log.e("TAG", "onBillingServiceDisconnected: ")
        }
    })
}

private fun loadAllSKUs() = if (billingClient.isReady) {
    val param = SkuDetailsParams
        .newBuilder()
        .setSkusList(skuList)
        .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
        .build()

    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(param) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
        // Process the result.
        if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList!!.isNotEmpty()) {
            for (skuDetails in skuDetailsList) {
                if (skuDetails.sku == productId) {


                    tv_singleAudio_price.text = skuDetails.price
                    realAmount = skuDetails.price

                    Log.e(TAG, "===loadAllSKUs: price: ${skuDetails.price}")
                    Log.e(TAG, "===loadAllSKUs: original price: ${skuDetails.originalPrice}")

                    rl_single_plan.setOnClickListener {
                        isInAppPurchase = true
                        isSubscribtion = false
                        val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams
                            .newBuilder()
                            .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                            .build()
                        billingClient.launchBillingFlow(requireActivity(), billingFlowParams)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else {
    println("Billing Client not ready")
}
```

Comment: where did you define `skuDetails`? Also this seems to be in Kotlin, do you have the equal in java?